# Firebase database update is removing child data

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am writing an event list app, It has a hierarchy of Event > Part > Step.  After I've created an event, I can "go into" the event and see the list of "parts" which contain a list of "steps".

The way I've structured my database is so that I have an object sorted by user ID to show the events and its details, then if I click on that event, I go into it, now looking at a `parts` object.  The parts object looks something like this:

```
parts:
    eventID1:
        partID1:
            startDateTime:value,
            endDateTime:value,
            title:value,
            ...
        partID2:
            startDateTime:value,
            endDateTime:value,
            title:value,
            ...
        etc.
```

This works well, I pull all parts per event ID.  The problem comes with steps.  When I add a step to a part, I put it in two places (using `update`); one in a steps table and one in the part itself, adding a new key:value to the `part`

the steps object looks like this:

```
steps:
    eventID1:
        partID1:
            stepID1:
                title:value,
                startDateTime:value,
                etc.
            stepID2:
                title:value,
                startDateTime:value,
                etc.
```

And finally (the problem area) the part object is updated to look like this:

```
parts:
    eventID1:
        partID1:
            startDateTime:value,
            endDateTime:value,
            title:value,
            ...
            steps:
                stepID1:
                    title:value,
                    startDateTime:value,
                    etc.
                stepID2:
                    title:value,
                    startDateTime:value,
                    etc.
        partID2:
            startDateTime:value,
            endDateTime:value,
            title:value,
            ...
        etc.
```

I've added the steps within the parts above (again, using `update`).  The problem is now when I edit the part's title or date, It returns as updated but there are no steps within.  It erases the steps.

Each `event`, `part` and `step` have the same structure, so I've combined all of this into a single function (using ionic 3/angular4)

```
  update(action, type, eid, pid, sid, title, location, startDateTime) {
    console.log("Firebase Database Receiving: ", action, type, eid, pid, sid, title, location, startDateTime);
    let key = (action === "add") ? this.ref.push().key : null;
    console.log(key);
    let update;
    let object = {
      startDateTime: startDateTime,
      startDateTimeEpoch:  moment(startDateTime).format("X"),
      endDateTime: startDateTime,
      endDateTimeEpoch:  moment(startDateTime).format("X"),
      title: title,
      type: type,
      roles: {
        [this.firebaseAuthentication.uid]: "admin",
      },
      location: {
        title: location,
        street: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        zip: '',
        timeZone: ''
      },
    };
    if(type === "events"){
      key = (key) ? key : eid;
      if(action !== "delete") {
        update = {
          ['events/' + key]: object,
          ['roles/' + this.firebaseAuthentication.uid + '/' + key]: object
        }
      } else {
        console.log("delete event", key);
        update = {
          ['events/' + key]: null,
          ['roles/' + this.firebaseAuthentication.uid + '/' + key]: null,
          ['parts/' + key]: null,
          ['steps/' + key]:null
        }
      }
    } else if(type === "parts") {
      key = (key) ? key : pid;
      if(action !== "delete") {
        update = {
/************ . Here is the update object . ***********/
          ['parts/' + eid + '/' + key]: object
        }
      } else {
        update = {
          ['parts/' + eid + '/' + key]: null,
          ['steps/' + eid + '/' + key]: null
        }
      }
    } else if(type === "steps") {
      key = (key) ? key : sid;
      if(action !== "delete") {
        update = {
          ['parts/' + eid + '/' + pid + '/steps/' + key]: object,
          ['steps/' + eid + '/' + pid + '/' + key]: object
        }
      } else {
        update = {
          ['parts/' + eid + '/' + pid + '/steps/' + key]: null,
          ['steps/' + eid + '/' + pid + '/' + key]: null
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(object, update);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
/**************** . Finally the actual update function ************/
      this.ref.update(update).then(success => {
        resolve(success);
      }, error => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  }
```

This basically iterates through, the specific `action/type` combination is `edit`/`part`.

From what I've read about firebase's `update()`, it should not be destructive to any data within the object that it's not touching.  This is acting like `set()` should, but I do not want that obviously.

Any thoughts? Frank?

Comment: You've pasted a whole bunch of code and a minimal repro would be more helpful. Biggest thing to remember is that you have to put *all of the specificity* in the slash-delimited path. An update will overwrite everything at the key level, so you can't do any nested objects unless you're wanting to overwrite the whole thing.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh, Yes, I have pasted a lot of code, but it's all pertinent (besides the two other update statements).  As for the update, if I were to put a blank `steps` item in that object, would it not overwrite what's in there?   (not a great example because steps would be in everything at that point, but just checking the point)

Comment: My point was if I do `update({'foo/bar': {baz: 'qux', some: 'thing'})` everything under `foo/bar` is overwritten. Instead I should do `update({'foo/bar/baz': 'qux', 'foo/bar/some': 'thing'})`. I'm not sure if that's the problem here because there's too much code to sort through and I've not the time :)

Comment: @MichaelBleigh, Thank you for your valuable, valuable time, though after reading too much on updates with firebase (especially [here](https://medium.com/@jasonbyrne/closer-look-at-firebase-set-versus-update-eceff34d056b)), the way I'm doing this should work fine.  It ignores duplicate values and only updates the values that have changed, also if I only update a single value, it would not delete all of the other fields (as `set` does).  But don't worry about it anymore, I don't want to waste any more of your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather from your code the update function works as I would expect (from experience rather than documentation ). What I mean to say is that updating on a key by setting it to an object does exactly that, it sets the key value to the object you passed. An example:

users:

- nik

  - age:18
  - id:1
- george

  - age:29
  - id:2

let obj={age:24};

calling update({nik:obj}) would actually set nik to have the value of the object you provide (thus deleting id). Stands to reason right? Well firebase does say about update:

> If you want to write to multiple children of a database location at the same time without overwriting other child nodes, you can use the update method as shown below:

What might be not clear is that it means other child nodes at the same level with the key you are updating (that would be george).

Comment: My experimentation shows the same. As well as the snide comments by Michael above.  You're right that it sounds a bit strange how they word it, but pointing it out makes sense.  To firebase, child nodes are more top level items, rather than children of the object you're editing.  It's understandable now

Answer (score 1):

It's the 'null' causing it, as per my usage of firebase so far that I can update the object and remove key pair from the object in a single update call.

```
object: {

 key1: value1, 

key2: null // this key will be removed as it is set to null

}
```

Hopefully this helps someone